# React ternary operator return jsx and string returns an Object

Tags: reactjs, antd, conditional-operator

I need to check if the form has been submitted, if it was successfull then display one thing if not another. The code I have is

```
                   {success !== undefined ? 
                        success ? <CheckOutlined /> + ' Subscribed' : (<CloseOutlined /> + ' Error!' )
                    : 'Subscribe'}
```

Undefined is the first state when the form is first loaded.
What I get returned after the form is submitted successfully is

```
[object Object] Subscribed
```

If I don't add the string everything is fine and I can see the jsx. How can I get them both to view using ternary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are concatenating JSX element in string that's why it is giving [Object Object] Subscribed. Also wrap icon and string with `React.Fragment`. Correct way is:

```js
{success !== undefined
            ? success
              ? (<><CheckOutlined />  " Subscribed"</>)
              : (<><CloseOutlined />  " Error!"</>)
            : "Subscribe"}
```

Comment: I get an error : ')' expected. I'm using react + typescript

Comment: Can you show code that you have written?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-montalcini-9zcmuv?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: You just have to warp icon and text with `React.Fragment`. I have updated the answer you can check that.

Comment: eslint error cant now

Answer (score 0):

Just try `success ? (<CheckOutlined /> Subscribed) : (<CloseOutlined /> Error!)`

Comment: I get an error : ')' expected. 
I'm using react + typescript